# Why is the inside of a cell both more acidic and more negative than its environment?

Tags: acid-base, ph, ions

In a very simplistic way of thinking, an acidic solution has more positively charged $\ce{H+}$ ions present, whereas a basic solution has more negatively charged $\ce{OH-}$ ions present.

Can that be simply reconciled with the fact that (1) the [intracellular pH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intracellular_pH) of about 6.8 is more acidic than the intercellular pH of about 7.3, and that (2) a typical cellular [membrane potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_potential) is -40 to -80 mV?

Comment: Are you talking about mammalian cells?

Comment: @airhuff, I can accept that as a candidate for best answer if you post as an answer and if no one else weighs in

Comment: @Bob, I was thinking about human cells, so yes, sort of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH−}$ are not the only ions at play here.

The selective permeability of different cellular membranes for different anions (i.e. $\ce{Cl−}$) and cations (i.e. $\ce{K+, Na+, Ca^{2+}, Mg^{2+},}$ etc.) results in charge separation. Cellular membrane potentials are thereby created, with or without an intercellular / intracellular pH gradient.